# StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying to perform a loop over school from all districts and blooks and collect the data from table. but when i use click() for go button it shows error ("StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document") in (" if (k.text=='Select School'):")line. can anyone help me.

```
import requests
import scrapy
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://rajshaladarpan.nic.in/SD1/Home/Public/EmployeeSearch.aspx'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_rbtSchOffSeclection').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_btnSearch').click()

dist=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select'))
for i in dist.options:
    if i.text == '--Select District--':
        continue
    dist.select_by_visible_text(i.text)
    print(i.text)
    dis.append(i.text)
    block=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/select'))
    for bloc in block.options:
        if (bloc.text == 'Select Block') or (bloc.text == 'ALL') or (bloc.text == ''):
            continue
        block.select_by_visible_text(bloc.text)
        print(bloc.text)
        time.sleep(10)
        school=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/select'))
        for k in school.options:
            if (k.text=='Select School'):
                continue
            print(k.text)
            time.sleep(2)
            school.select_by_visible_text(k.text)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_Button6"]').submit()
            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: in my test your dist dont find select. Its for find district? so if yes you have an id ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_ddlDistrictsch

Answer (score 0):

**org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**

The literal meaning is about , The referenced element is **out of date** , No longer attached to the current page . Usually , This is because the page has been refreshed or skipped , The solution is , Reuse findElement or findElements Method to locate the element .

so you have to change all your loops and refresh each time to avoid this error.

i show you the fix for district, block and school ,  i have fixed the number of each item  to 5 for the test.

And i suggest you to search the id when available instead xpath

```
driver.maximize_window()
url='https://rajshaladarpan.nic.in/SD1/Home/Public/EmployeeSearch.aspx'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_rbtSchOffSeclection').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_btnSearch').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_ddlDistrictsch')))
dist=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_ddlDistrictsch'))
nbrdist = len(dist.options)
nbrdist = 5 if nbrdist > 5 else nbrdist
print("nbr district", nbrdist)
for r in range(0, nbrdist):
    try:
        d = dist.options[r]
        if d.text == '--Select District--':
            continue
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        dist = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_ddlDistrictsch'))
        d = dist.options[r]
        if d.text == '--Select District--':
            continue

    dist.select_by_visible_text(d.text)
    print(d.text)

    time.sleep(2)
    block=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_ddlBlock'))

    nbrblock = len(block.options)
    nbrblock = 5 if nbrblock > 5 else nbrblock
    print("nbr block:",nbrblock)
    for b in range(0, nbrblock):
        try:
            bloc = block.options[b]
            if (bloc.text == 'Select Block') or (bloc.text == 'ALL') or (bloc.text == ''):
                continue
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            block = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_ddlBlock'))
            bloc = block.options[b]
        if (bloc.text == 'Select Block') or (bloc.text == 'ALL') or (bloc.text == ''):
            continue

        block.select_by_visible_text(bloc.text)
        print(bloc.text)
        time.sleep(2)

        school=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlSchool'))
        nbrschool = len(school.options)
        print("nbr school:", nbrschool)
        nbrschool = 5 if nbrschool > 5 else nbrschool
        for s in range(0, nbrschool):
            try:
                sc = school.options[s]
                if (sc.text=='Select School'):
                    continue

            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                school = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlSchool'))
                sc = school.options[s]
                #print("ersc", len(school.options))
                if (sc.text == 'Select School'):
                    continue

            print(sc.text)
            school.select_by_visible_text(sc.text)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeDetail_Button6"]').click()
            time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: it has some errors again

Comment: the answer is a bit vague.....

Comment: i have relaunched the scrip and no problem. i have done a little video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLBybMPSyHTzOxYXfW3A-uAIq5fYzIbw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: let me rerun this sir

Comment: it is only selecting first 4-5 schools not going through all the schools. can you fix this too.

Comment: yes its just for the test, you just comment nbrschool = 5 if nbrschool > 5 else nbrschool